# ¿Cómo leer recursos desde WEB-INF con spring-boot desplegando en JBoss?

Tags: aplicación-web, spring-boot

En una aplicación web que usa **spring-boot** y es desplegada sobre **JBoss EAP 7.0**, tengo el siguiente problema; Tengo que leer un fichero que está en el directorio **WEB-INF** de mi paquete **WAR** (usamos el plugin de maven para producir un WAR desplegable en lugar del fichero JAR generado por spring-boot), para la lectura uso la siguiente línea

```
 leerArchivo(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("directorio/fichero.ext").getPath()
```

Esto funciona cuando desarrollamos y desplegamos la aplicación con la tarea **maven** `clean spring-boot-run` Pero cuando llevamos el **WAR** al servidor **JBoss**,  obtengo un honorable `java.io.FileNotFoundException`, y estoy bastante seguro de que el fichero se encuentra en el directorio WEB-INF de mi WAR.

Como solución a esto hice lo siguiente

1. Inyecté un **WebApplicationContext**  en la clase donde necesito leer el fichero
2. Escribí la siguiente línea para obtener el **Path** del fichero

```
webApplicationContext.getServletContext().getRealPath("WEB-INF/classes/keys/public.pub")
```

Esto resuelve el problema en el **JBoss**  pero ahora obtengo `java.io.FileNotFoundException` cuando ejecuto la aplicación con la tarea de **maven**

¿ Conocen alguna manera de leer un fichero dentro de **WEB-INF** independientemente de si despliego la aplicación en un servidor de aplicaciones(com JBoss, Tomcat, Glasfish, etc) o si la ejecuto con **maven**, un **JAR** o alguna otra forma ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No encontré una solución mejor que usar el ClassLoader del hilo actual.

```
ClassLoader contextClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream inputStream = contextClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(relativePath);
```

Y utilizo el InputStream reader en mi caso para leer el fichero.